# Laravel shows the content upside down

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following blade template:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">        
        @extends('layouts._navbar')        

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
```

Laravel first shows this:

```
<main class="py-4">
    @yield('content')
</main>
```

And then:

```
@extends('layouts._navbar')
```

How do I to show the contents in the right order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `@extends('layout._navbar')` to `@include('layout._navbar')`.

Currently you're trying to push your blade file into the `layout._navbar`, instead of including it.

[Laravel documentation on Blade Subviews](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views)

Your blade file will look like this after the edit:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">        
        @include('layouts._navbar')        

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `include` instead of `extends` :

```
<body>
    <div id="app">        
        @include('layouts._navbar')        

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
```